# VBA OFFSET cannot be found

Tags: excel, vba

Excel has a function called "OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])" and i would like to use VBA code to perform this function.

However, i am not able to find this OFFSET function in VBA. In fact i can only find Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset) in VBA code which is not what i am looking for.

I tried using macro for "OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])" and the result i gotten is this: ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=OFFSET(R[-13]C[-1],1,2,4,1)". However this does not help because i need my argument to be a variable.

Please advice me how to perform this "OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])" in VBA code. Thank You

Comment: Not all formulas have a `WorksheetFunction` equivalent. What is your end goal? This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Offset and resize will do what you want.

Comment: @BigBen My goal is to create a secondary dropdown list. 
I have a table with headers. My first dropdown list is the header at the 1st row of  my table. My second dropdown list is the column under each header. 

I used data validation for my first dropdown list. I plan to use offset command for my second dropdown list.

I am looking for the most efficient way to do it because i have more than 50 tables.

Comment: Why not create dependent combo boxes?

Comment: Confused why you need VBA then. I would add more detail to your question, perhaps including a screenshot.

Comment: @BigBen I would need VBA because i have plenty of tables. So i would want the dropdown list to be flexible to be able to represent all my tables. Provided if that is even possible

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough detail to be able to provide a satisfactory answer then.

Comment: @e_conomics I see. Ok i will consider that .